# How to fetch all files and folder store on box.com using API?

Tags: salesforce, box-api

I have access token for box.com and I want to retrieve all files and folder from box.com how do I achieve this. Please provide me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

box.com provides end point URL to fulfill above requirement.

So you have to first set header with authorization :bearer access Token.

And please make all of your parameters url encoded.

Hope this well help.